# Using closure to decorate a class's methods

Tags: python, python-decorators

I need to generate a class that would mimic another class's method set and behave like the latter via a proxy. e.g. If `Base` is the class to mimic and `Deleguate` is the class which needs to act as `Base` then:

```
b = Base(args)
b.any_function()
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
d = Deleguate(b)
d.any_function()
```

If `Deleguate` uses a function that already exists in `Base`, it won't be overwritten. It's the kind of behavior you expect with inheritance and method overriding. Inheritance is not an option in the context of the project I'm working on (among other constraint, I don't have access to the factory code). And that's what makes things complicated.

I therefore decided to code a "proxy" decorator :

```
import inspect

def proxy(bridge, target):
    def proxyfy(cls):
        for _, func in inspect.getmembers(target, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
            fname = func.__name__
            if fname in cls.__dict__:
                print 'ignoring %s.%s' % (cls, fname)
                continue
            print 'adding %s.%s' % (cls, fname)
            def proxy_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
                print 'calling %s.%s.%s' % (cls, bridge, fname)
                bridge_member = getattr(self, bridge)
                return getattr(bridge_member, fname)(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(cls, fname, proxy_func)
        return cls
    return proxyfy

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self._i = i

    def __bar(self):
        print 0

    def foo(self):
        print self._i

    def foo2(self):
        print 2 * self._i


@proxy('_proxy', Base)
class Deleguate(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self._proxy = base

    def foo2(self):
        print 4 * self._proxy._i

d = Deleguate(Base(1))
d.__bar() # d._proxy.__bar()
d.foo()   # d._proxy.foo()
d.foo2()  # d.foo2()
```

I get the following output :

```
adding <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.__bar
ignoring <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.__init__
adding <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.foo
ignoring <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.foo2
calling <class '__main__.Deleguate'>._proxy.foo2
2
calling <class '__main__.Deleguate'>._proxy.foo2
2
4
```

I thought that `setattr(cls, fname, proxy_func)` would assign a new closure, but the arguments are overwritten at each loop step and only the arguments of the last function `foo2` are kept. Therefore calling any "generated" function of `Deleguate` uses `foo2` arguments...

**Why are the closure arguments being overwritten ? Is there a way to generate that kind of proxy code ?** The expected output is :

```
adding <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.__bar
ignoring <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.__init__
adding <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.foo
ignoring <class '__main__.Deleguate'>.foo2
calling <class '__main__.Deleguate'>._proxy.__bar
0
calling <class '__main__.Deleguate'>._proxy.foo
1
4
```

Comment: `fname` in `proxy_func()` is a *closure*; it is not looked up until you call `proxy_func()`, at which point it's value is still bound to the last value (`foo2` in this case), **not** the value it was bound to when you created the nested function.

Comment: The workaround is to create a local variable somewhere to bind the value to in the loop; a separate factory function would do that, or by giving `proxy_func()` a keyword argument that binds the `fname` as a default to the function object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did that. But it fails with `AttributeError: 'Base' object has no attribute '__bar'` on `d.__bar() # d._proxy.__bar()`. :'(

Comment: @MartijnPieters Its been half an hour since I started working on this. :( I changed the signature like this `def proxy_func(self, fname=fname, *args, **kwargs):`.

Comment: @thefourtheye: That is because double-underscore names are mangled; see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers

Comment: @MartijnPieters Damn. Without you, I would never have figured this one out. Thanks a lot :) Please add an answer, it will really be useful for future reference :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: Nah, this is a dupe, as it stands. I already linked to my canonical answer on the subject.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed. But, even if he figures out the closure thing, it would be difficult to understand the  mangling part, I believe.

Comment: @thefourtheye: But that's a side-issue; a comment suffices to cover that issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the reference. I wasn't looking for the right keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions create closures, loops do not. The variable name `fname` 
is a local variable in `proxyfy`. The nested function `proxy_func` refers to this local variable. But at the time when the nested function is called, the `for-loop`

```
    for _, func in inspect.getmembers(target, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
```

has completed, and the local variable `fname` references its last value at the end of the loop, which happens to be `'foo2'`.
So no matter what method you call, each `proxy_func` ends up calling `foo2`.

To bind different values of `fname` to each `proxy_func`, you could use a new keyword parameter, `bname` with a default value. The default value is bound to the function at *definition-time* not at the time the function in run. So if use

```
    for bname, func in inspect.getmembers(target, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
```

and use this `bname` as the default value:

```
        def proxy_func(self, bname=bname, *args, **kwargs):
```

then each `proxy_func` will call the appropriate `bname`.

So, with minimal changes to your code, you could add a keyword parameter with default value to `proxy_func` to remember the current method name:

```
def proxy(bridge, target):
    def proxyfy(cls):
        for bname, func in inspect.getmembers(target, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
            fname = func.__name__
            if fname in cls.__dict__:
                print 'ignoring %s.%s' % (cls, fname)
                continue
            print 'adding %s.%s' % (cls, fname)
            def proxy_func(self, bname=bname, *args, **kwargs):
                print 'calling %s.%s.%s' % (cls, bridge, bname)
                bridge_member = getattr(self, bridge)
                return getattr(bridge_member, bname)(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(cls, fname, proxy_func)
        return cls
    return proxyfy
```

However, I think using `__getattr__` might be easier:

```
def proxy(bridge):
    def proxyfy(cls):
        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            target = getattr(self, bridge)
            if attr.startswith('__') and not attr.endswith('__'):
                # unmangle
                attr = '_{}{}'.format(type(target).__name__, attr)
            return getattr(target, attr)
        setattr(cls, '__getattr__', __getattr__)
        return cls
    return proxyfy
```

---

Here's a runnable example:

```
import inspect

def proxy(bridge, target):
    def proxyfy(cls):
        for bname, func in inspect.getmembers(target, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
            fname = func.__name__
            if fname in cls.__dict__:
                print 'ignoring %s.%s' % (cls, fname)
                continue
            print 'adding %s.%s' % (cls, fname)
            def proxy_func(self, bname=bname, *args, **kwargs):
                print 'calling %s.%s.%s' % (cls, bridge, bname)
                bridge_member = getattr(self, bridge)
                return getattr(bridge_member, bname)(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(cls, fname, proxy_func)
        return cls
    return proxyfy

def proxy(bridge):
    def proxyfy(cls):
        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            target = getattr(self, bridge)
            if attr.startswith('__') and not attr.endswith('__'):
                # unmangle
                attr = '_{}{}'.format(type(target).__name__, attr)
            return getattr(target, attr)
        setattr(cls, '__getattr__', __getattr__)
        return cls
    return proxyfy

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self._i = i

    def __bar(self):
        print 0

    def foo(self):
        print self._i

    def foo2(self):
        print 2 * self._i


# @proxy('_proxy', Base)
@proxy('_proxy')
class Delegate(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self._proxy = base

    def foo2(self):
        print 4 * self._proxy._i

d = Delegate(Base(1))
d.__bar() # d._proxy.__bar()
d.foo()   # d._proxy.foo()
d.foo2()  # d.foo2()
```

Comment: Thank you! Your very first sentence sum it all up. Plus you made the distinction between `bname` and `fname`, which matters when playing with mangled methods.